# Using ajax with sweetalert2 to post data to node js

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to insert data to mongodb via node js from a form coded in ejs but i needed some sort of notification once submission is done and so i used sweetalert2 with ajax. The challenge is, it keeps telling me: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $.ajax is not a function**

```
swal({
        title: '<b>Hello  ' + fname + ' your booking summary<b>',
        html: '<b>Room Type:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;' + rooms + '<br> ' +
        '<b>Check In:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;' + datein + '<br>' +
        '<b>Check Out:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;' + dateout + '<br>' +
        '<b>Payment Method:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp;Cash on arrival<br>' +
        '<br>' +
        '<p><b>Total Amount:</b> <span class="badge badge-success">$' + amount + '</span><br></p>'
        ,
        type: 'info',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirm Booking',
        preConfirm: function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var data = {};
                data.email = email;
                data.pay = paymethod;
                data.checkin_date = datein;
                data.checkout_date = dateout;
                data.phonenumber = mobile;
                data.current_date = email;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/addcustomer",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log("Data submitted");
                        resolve(response)
                    },
                    error: function(a, b, c){
                        reject("error message")
                    }
                })
            })
        },
        allowOutsideClick: false
       }).then((result)=>{
        console.log(result.value);
        if(result.value){
            swal('Congratulations', 'Your Booking order is well received', 'success');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Has you import jQuery?

Comment: You sure you've got the jQuery namespace in there?

Comment: Actually, i got the solution, the issue was with the version of jquery i was using. I replaced jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js with jquery-3.1.1.min.js as suggested here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21766